# How to send an email with attachment in domino server using notes java api?

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have Java code to send email in domino server without attachment. I want to get it working with attachments also.

```
try {
       Session dominoSession = NotesFactory.createSession( host, username, password );
       System.out.println("USER Detail : "+dominoSession.getUserName());
       Database dominoDb = dominoSession.getDatabase( host, mailbox );

       Document memo = dominoDb.createDocument();
       memo.appendItemValue( "Form", "Memo" );
       memo.appendItemValue( "Importance", "1" );
       memo.appendItemValue( "CopyTo", copyTo );
       memo.appendItemValue( "Subject", subject );
       memo.appendItemValue( "Body", message );
       memo.send( false, sendTo );

       dominoDb.recycle();
       dominoSession.recycle();
      }
      catch ( NotesException e )
      {
       System.out.println( "Error - " + e.toString() );
      }
      catch ( Exception e )
      {
       System.out.println( "Error - " + e.toString() );
      }
```

Comment: Read teh javadoc of the API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should not use appendItemValue().
You use replaceItemValue() to insert data into text fields.

Second, the field 'body' is a rich text dfield. You need to use the methods and properties of the NotesRichTextItem class to work with rich text. Then you also have the ability to attach files. It is all described in the help file, with examples.